# Combine multiple files into Zip file and download that zip file chunk by chunk from Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to download lot's of file from azure storage. So is it possible to combine those files into zip file and download that zip file chunk by chunk and save it locally.

Can anyone give me some idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Combine multiple files into a Zip file and download that zip file chunk by chunk from Azure Storage

You can use the below sample codes to download multiple files with zip files locally which I tried in my environment.

**Python:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import zipfile
import io

def download_files_from_azure_storage(connection_string, container_name, files_to_download, zip_file_name):
    # Connect to Azure Storage account
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "w") as zipf:
        for file_name in files_to_download:
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file_name)
            download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
            with io.BytesIO() as file_buffer:
                for chunk in download_stream.chunks():
                    file_buffer.write(chunk)
                file_buffer.seek(0)
                zipf.writestr(file_name, file_buffer.read())

zip_file_name = "downloaded_files.zip"
connection_string = "<your connection string>"  
container_name = "test"
files_to_download = ["authorizationerror.docx", "barcode.docx", "biceperror.docx","browserupload.docx","demo.pdf","datamovementazcpy.docx","datalakestoragesas.docx","datalakegen2access.docx"]  #files which you need to download

print("File is downloaded with zip successfully")

download_files_from_azure_storage(connection_string, container_name, files_to_download, zip_file_name)
```

**Output:**

```
File is downloaded with zip successfully
```

[image]

[image]

**C#**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.IO.Compression;


public static class storagezip
{
    public static async Task DownloadFilesFromstorageaszip(string connectionString, string containerName, List<string> filesToDownload, string zipFileName)
    {
        // Connect to Azure Storage account
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (string fileName in filesToDownload)
            {
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName);
                    using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                    {
                        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify your Azure Storage connection string
        string connectionString = "your connection string";

        // Specify the container and files you want to download and zip
        string containerName = "test";
        List<string> filesToDownload = new List<string> { "authorizationerror.docx", "barcode.docx", "biceperror.docx", "browserupload.docx", "demo.pdf", "datamovementazcpy.docx", "datalakestoragesas.docx", "datalakegen2access.docx" }; //files which you need to download

        // Specify the name of the zip file to be created
        string zipFileName = "downloaded_files.zip";

        await storagezip.DownloadFilesFromstorageaszip(connectionString, containerName, filesToDownload, zipFileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Files downloaded and zipped successfully!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]